# Form Submission/POST using Requests in Python

Tags: python, forms, python-requests

I'm trying to submit a form to a website using the requests module in Python but my form is not submitting correctly. I can submit the form correctly manually on the site but I assume something is wrong with my code that is causing the Python submission to fail. I can successfully login to the website and visit pages/issue GET requests using Python. I can issue a GET request to the page that I submit the form to and it will successfully load, i.e. the requests login works. I have included all of my output below including the Python code, an invalid form submission in Python and a valid form submission from the browser. This may be overkill but I am inexperienced with this and am not sure what is necessary.

My code to login is:

```
    s = requests.Session()

    data = s.get(login_url)
    authToken = re.search(('name="authenticity_token"[\s]'
                       'type="hidden"[\s]+value="(.+)"'), \
                      data.text).group(1)
    data_dict = {
    'utf8': '&#x2713;',
    'authenticity_token': authToken,
    'admin[email]': username,
    'admin[password]': password,
    'admin[remember_me]': '1',
    'commit': 'Sign in'
    }

    s.post(login_url, data_dict)
```

This successfully logs me in and I can submit GET requests to any page and get valid results.

My code to submit the form:

```
    payload = {
    'utf8': '&#x2713;',
    'authenticity_token': authToken,
    'progress_course[name]': name,
    'progress_course[description]': desc,
    'commit': 'Create Course'
    }


    headers = {
            'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate',
            'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8',
            'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
            'Connection':'keep-alive',
            'Content-Length':'176',
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Host':'xxx.com',
            'Origin':'https://xxx.com',
            'Referer':'https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses/new',
            'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36'
    }

    response = s.post(path,data=payload,headers=headers)
```

My form submission does not work. Here is the python logging module output:

The POST:

```
send: 'POST /workshop/progress/courses HTTP/1.1
Origin: https://xxx.com\r\nContent-Length: 181
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Host: xxx.com
Referer: https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses/new
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Cookie: _brainfit_session=xxx; remember_admin_token=xxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
progress_course%5Bdescription%5D=pytest&utf8=%26%23x2713%3B&commit=Create+Course&progress_course%5Bname%5D=pytest&authenticity_token=xxx
```

The reply to the POST. You can see that this comes from the sign-in page rather than generating a new page as seen in the correct output further down.

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 01:57:46 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Status: 302 Found
header: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: Location: https://xxx.com/admins/sign_in
header: Cache-Control: no-cache
header: X-Request-Id: 983472d4-8954-4106-904a-38ea3b6a76a1
header: X-Runtime: 0.039963
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"POST /workshop/progress/courses HTTP/1.1" 302 None
```

Redirect GETs and replies. I may be mistaken in what these actually are:

```
send: 'GET /admins/sign_in HTTP/1.1
Origin: https://xxx.com
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: xxx.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses/new
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Cookie: _brainfit_session=xxx; remember_admin_token=xxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 01:57:46 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Status: 302 Found
header: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: Location: https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses
header: Cache-Control: no-cache
header: Set-Cookie: _brainfit_session=xxx; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
header: X-Request-Id: 9e5535d6-143c-4e98-8bb4-35dd29ab045d
header: X-Runtime: 0.007505
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /admins/sign_in HTTP/1.1" 302 None


send: 'GET /workshop/progress/courses HTTP/1.1
Origin: https://xxx.com
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: xxx.com
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses/new
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Cookie: _brainfit_session=exxx; remember_admin_token=xxx
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Server: nginx
header: Date: Tue, 02 Dec 2014 01:57:46 GMT
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: keep-alive
header: Status: 200 OK
header: Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
header: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
header: X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
header: X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
header: Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
header: Set-Cookie: _brainfit_session=xxx; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
header: X-Request-Id: 4e759b60-af1c-4f39-b033-71ff99b62df4
header: X-Runtime: 0.019001
header: Content-Encoding: gzip
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /workshop/progress/courses HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

The POST headers of a properly submitted form on the site:

```
Remote Address:xxx
Request URL:https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses
Request Method:POST
Status Code:302 Found
```

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:176
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:__utma=xxx; __utmc=xxx; __utmz=xxx.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|
utmctr=xxx; km_lv=x; kvcd=xxx; km_ai=xxx; km_ni=xxx; km_uq=xxx; has_logged_in=true; WT_FPC=id=xxx; _ga=xxx; _brainfit_session=xxx
Host:xxx.com
Origin:https://xxx.com
Referer:https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
```

**Form Data**

```
utf8:✓
authenticity_token:xxx
progress_course[name]:test03
progress_course[description]:test03
commit:Create Course
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 01 Dec 2014 14:01:37 GMT
Location:https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses/44
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:_brainfit_session=xxx; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Status:302 Found
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=31536000
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:8bb04242-bc5a-408f-99a5-9d8bf4eeb611
X-Runtime:0.028559
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Once the form is correctly submitted there is also a GET response from the page it redirects to. I've excluded additional output here but it can be added if it will help resolve the problem.

```
Remote Address:xxx
Request URL:https://xxx.com/workshop/progress/courses/44
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Comment: A few obvious things wrong with your code: (1) If that's your actual POST, with no blank line before the POST data, then there is no POST data, just an extra malformed header. (2) You're passing a hard-coded `Content-Length` instead of letting requests do it for you, and it's about 5 or 6 characters short, which means the server may well stop reading and never see your auth token. (3) Your cookies are missing many of the values, at least one of which (`has_logged_in`) looks like it might be relevant.

Comment: Hopefully `xxx.com` is not the actual web site :)

Comment: More generally, why are you trying to manually do so much of what requests will do for you? Unless you know requests is getting it wrong, and you know what the right answer is, don't do that.

Comment: @mhawke: You don't think porn sites (I'm assuming that's what's at xxx.com; not going to check while sitting at work…) can have courses and workshops and something called "brainfit" for their users? :)

Comment: @abarnert I was passing the headers because I wanted to find the error in my code. The form also does not submit when I do not specify the headers and let requests handle it. In reference to (1) are you referring to the Python logging output? In reference to (3) should I pass the cookies given to me upon login when I POST?

Comment: @davidkohn: The headers have meanings; passing headers that don't go with your request will just confuse the server. (1) Yes, the Python logging output shows no blank line after the header. Is that what you're actually sending? (You can find out by running Wireshark, re-aiming the client at `localhost:8888` while running `nc -kl 8888` in a terminal, etc.) (3) Yes, you probably need to pass on the cookies, either manually or by letting requests do it.